# programming task ask

Tags: c++

```
C++ Template:
class MyClass
{
public:
 getNiCount(...)
  {
  }
 replaceNiWithNI(...)
  {
  }
};
int main()
{
 const char *szTestString1 = "Ni nI NI nI Ni";
 const wchar_t *szTestString2 = L"Ni nI NI nI Ni";
 // Invoke getNiCount(...) of class MyClass
 // Invoke replaceNiWithNI(...) of class MyClass
 // Display on screen: "Found X occurrences of Ni. New string: Y"
}
```

Task description:

1. Implement the two functions `getNiCount` and `replaceNiWithNI` of the class `MyClass`:

   - `getNiCount` should return the number of occurrences of "Ni" within `szTestString1/2` (case sensitive)
   - `replaceNiWithNI` should replace all occurrences of "Ni" in `szTestString1/2` with "NI" (case sensitive)
2. Invoke the two functions `getNiCount` and `replaceNiWithNI`.
3. Display the string given in the last comment on screen. `X` and `Y` should be replaced with the real values.
4. The class `MyClass` should be able to deal with both `szTestString1` (ASCII) and `szTestString2` (Unicode).

General requirements:

The code should be

- easy to understand and maintain (Priority 1)
- technically elegant (Priority 2)
- as (CPU) efficient as possible (Priority 3)

You’re allowed to use all techniques, toolkits and frameworks which are based on the C++ language.

my solution (incomplete)

The logic is below...
However in my system the function2 "replace" is crashing. Cannot get it fixed.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
public:
 void getNiCount(const char*,const wchar_t*);
  //cout<<"\nCount is :"<<count;

void replaceNiWithNI(const char*,const wchar_t*);

};

void MyClass::getNiCount(const char* x,const wchar_t* y)
{
     int count=0;
     int ycount=0;
   for(int i=0; x[i]!='\0';i++)
   {
       if(x[i]=='N')
       {   if(x[i+1]=='i')
                          count++;
       }
       }
   for(int i=0; y[i]!='\0';i++)
   {
       if(y[i]=='N')
       {   if(y[i+1]=='i')
                          ycount++;
       }
       }
       cout<<"\nFound "<<count<<" occurences of Ni in String 1";
       cout<<"\nFound "<<ycount<<" occurences of Ni in String 2";
}

void MyClass:: replaceNiWithNI(const char* x,const wchar_t* y)
{    char* a;
     wchar_t* b;
     strcpy(a,x);


     for (int i=0;a[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         if (a[i]=='N')
         {  if(a[i+1]=='i')
            {
                           a[i+1]='I';
                           }
         }
         }
     for (int i=0;y[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         b[i]=y[i];
     }
     for (int i=0;b[i]!='\0';i++)
     {
         if (b[i]=='N')
         {  if(b[i+1]=='i')
            {
                           b[i+1]='I';
                           }
         }
     }

     cout<<"\nNew String 1 is :";
     puts(a);
     cout<<"\nNew String 2 is :";<<b

}


int main()
{
 const char *szTestString1 = "Ni nI NI nI Ni";
 const wchar_t *szTestString2 = L"Ni nI NI nI Ni";
 MyClass ob1;
 ob1.getNiCount(szTestString1,szTestString2);
 ob1.replaceNiWithNI(szTestString1,szTestString2);
 getchar();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is your homework, not ours. What did you try?

Comment: no it isnt , its an excercise .

Comment: An exercise for who? What is your question exactly?

Comment: i am just looking for an alternate or a better solution to the problem ..

Comment: First, show us your solution, and second, [there](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is better site to post it.

Comment: it is the 4th point in the task that i am not getting(ascii and unicode) . i hope it shows you the effort i made in doing my home work . making you more interested in giving a solution rather than going in to unneccesary details .

Comment: i cant post my soution for atleast 8hrs , that is wat the site says otherwise i would have .@ErikEsTT

Comment: @user1609824 you can post your solution as an edit to your post.

Comment: thanx @joe . i have posted my solution , now will you guys please help me out ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your program fails to compile because of the misplaced semi-colon in

   ```
   cout<<"\nNew String 2 is :";<<b
   ```
2. Your program crashes at `strcpy(a,x);` because you're copying into `a` which is uninitialised - it has no memory allocated.  You'd need to call `new` on `a` for this to work, which would also mean you'd need to know the size of the array required (another parameter for the function probably).
3. Using `std::string` and `std::wstring` is almost always preferable to dealing with raw char arrays. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032243/should-i-return-stdstrings) for example.  I see you'd probably already considered it since you've got `#include <string>`
4. Since you're required to perform identical operations on differing types, I suspect the point of the exercise might have been to use templates.
5. You said

   > `getNiCount` should return the number of occurrences...

   yet your `getNiCount` doesn't return anything.
6. `using namespace std;` is often [considered bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c).
7. It's generally worth [favouring pre-increments rather than post-increments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24901/is-there-a-performance-difference-between-i-and-i-in-c?answertab=votes#tab-top), although in this particular case, there's no overhead.

---

To give you an example including the recommendations above:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename StrType>
class MyClass {
 public:
  int getNiCount(const StrType& input) const;
  void replaceNiWithNI(StrType& input) const;
};

template<typename StrType>
int MyClass<StrType>::getNiCount(const StrType& input) const {
  int count = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i) {
    if (input[i] == 'N' && input[i + 1] == 'i')
      ++count;
  }
  return count;
}

template<typename StrType>
void MyClass<StrType>::replaceNiWithNI(StrType& input) const {
  for (int i = 0; i < input.size() - 1; ++i) {
    if (input[i] == 'N' && input[i + 1] == 'i')
      input[i + 1] = 'I';
  }
}


int main() {
  const char* szTestString1 = "Ni nI NI nI Ni";
  MyClass<std::string> ob1;
  std::string testString1(szTestString1);
  int count1 = ob1.getNiCount(testString1);
  ob1.replaceNiWithNI(testString1);
  std::cout << "Found " << count1 << " occurences of Ni in String 1.  "
            << "New string: " << testString1 << '\n';

  const wchar_t* szTestString2 = L"Ni nI NI nI Ni";
  MyClass<std::wstring> ob2;
  std::wstring testString2(szTestString2);
  int count2 = ob2.getNiCount(testString2);
  ob2.replaceNiWithNI(testString2);
  std::wcout << L"Found " << count2 << L" occurences of Ni in String 2.  "
             << L"New string: " << testString2 << '\n';

  getchar();
  return 0;
}
```

I've generally left the way you locate and replace the `Ni` chars as you had it.  There are more sophisticated options available in the [member functions of `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) and in [`<algorithm>` library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm).